# On icon hover Text display (slide or fade)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created the `ul` and there was `font awesome` icon and icon name.I just want to display text only when hover the icon.

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
    <li><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i><a href="#"><i> Facebook</i></a></li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i><a href="#"><i> Twitter</i></a></li>
      <li><i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i><a href="#"><i> Google plus</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And have you tried anything related to that?

Comment: which text ? where you want to show ? as a tooltip or on your page ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay  I want to add jquery Slide effect to when text show.

Answer (score 5):

try to use `+` css selector

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display: none;
  }
ul li i:hover + a{
  display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
    <li><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i><a href="#"><i> Facebook</i></a></li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i><a href="#"><i> Twitter</i></a></li>
      <li><i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i><a href="#"><i> Google plus</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

but as i understant, you cant use link when link is visible only when hovering icon, so i suggest you to wrap icon into anchor. For slide, or fade effect you will need transitions:

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  }
ul li a i:last-child{
  transition: max-width 0.5s ease;
  max-width:0;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }
ul li a:hover i:last-child{
  max-width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i><i> Facebook</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i><i> Twitter</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i><i> Google plus</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good.. thanks.. but i need to use jquery 'Slide' effect.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
    <li><i class='fa fa-facebook' title="facebook"></i><a href="#"><i> Facebook</i></a></li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-twitter' title="twitter"></i><a href="#"><i> Twitter</i></a></li>
      <li><i class='fa fa-google-plus' title="google-plus"></i><a href="#"><i> Google plus</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

a text will appear when you hover icon.

Comment: Noooooo... i mean when hover the icon with animation text display